# Breeze js expand and inlineCount

Tags: odata, breeze

I'm using Breeze js ver 1.4.1 in a project and I have this query:

```
    var query = breeze
                .EntityQuery.from("AnalyzeObjects")
                .expand("GatherTasks, GatherTasks.ObjectFactory")
                .where(predicate)
                .orderBy("Name")  
                .using(manager)
                .execute();
```

It works ok, but as I want to add server side paging I added the following:

```
    var query = breeze
                .EntityQuery.from("AnalyzeObjects")
                .expand("GatherTasks, GatherTasks.ObjectFactory")
                .where(predicate)
                .inlineCount()
                .orderBy("Name")
                .take(_take)
                .skip(_skip)                        
                .using(manager)
                .execute();
```

The thing is, the query is running ok, the inlineCount property is being returned but the expand clause stopped working. If I run the first query the "GatherTasks" navigation property is returned ok, but with the inlineCount property set it doesn't.
I'm using an OData endpoint implemmented in WCF Data Services.
Does anyone know a reason for this behaviour? Is it a bug on breeze js?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the problem.

In my test below:

```
test("expand not working with paging", function () {
    var manager = newEm();
    var predicate = Predicate.create("orderID", "<", 10500);
    stop();
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
        .from("Orders")
        .expand("orderDetails, orderDetails.product")
        .where(predicate)
        .inlineCount()
        .orderBy("orderDate")
        .take(2)
        .skip(1)
        .using(manager)
        .execute()
        .then(function (data) {
            var localQuery = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from('OrderDetails');

            var orderDetails = manager.executeQueryLocally(localQuery);
            ok(orderDetails.length > 0, "should not be empty");

            var localQuery2 = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from('Products');

            var products = manager.executeQueryLocally(localQuery2);
            ok(products.length > 0, "should not be empty");
        }).fail(testFns.handleFail).fin(start);
});
```

Both orderDetails and products are retrieved properly.
If you can provide a small solution reproducing the problem, we will be able to investigate further and find what the issue is.

Comment: I've done like you said, trying to query the local cache but even so it is not loading my navigation properties! I tried creating a model using Northwind database and it worked. My model has a lot of self referentials and I think breeze is getting lost on those properties.
I will soon provide an example with my model and then we can further look into this issue.
Thanks for the help for now!